# Preferring forward edges to cross edges during graph DFS traversal

Tags: graphs

It's well known that depth-first search order of a graph is (usually) not unique, and multiple orders are possible depending on the order in which successors are processed for each node. Let's consider rooted directed graphs in the following discussion.

Muchnick 1997 gives an example:
[image: Two DFSes of a simple graph].

Intuitively, DFS with (more) forward edges is "better"/"more useful" than one with (more) cross edges. Is there a methodology/algorithm for ordering successor selection to construct such DFS spanning trees (like (b) in the example above)? (Of course, an algorithm better than generating all possible DFS trees in exponential time and then selecting "the best".)

Comment: Do you imply a directed acyclic graph? "Intuitively, DFS with (more) forward edges is 'better'/'more useful' than one with (more) cross edges". Although I would agree intuitively, can you actually explain why?

Comment: "Do you imply a directed acyclic graph?" - No, as the question says, "a graph", which is hopefully good enough rendition of "an arbitrary graph" is English ;-).

Comment: "Although I would agree intuitively, can you actually explain why?" Well, e.g. when graph represents a CFG (control flow graph) in the program analysis. The graph on the left could represent `if (a and b) then D else C`construct. The DFS tree in the middle, with forward edge, arguably "preserves" "shape" of this meaning, while one with cross edge arguably "obfuscates".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about direct acyclic graph. I guess you mean an undirected graph even if all graphs in your question are directed acyclic graph. By the way, how far have you tried in constructing a wanted algorithm?

Comment: On your explanation about the advantage of graph (b), you mentioned `if (a and b) then D else C`. However, `a` and `b` are symmetric in that snippet while A and B in graph (a) are not.

Comment: "I guess you mean an undirected graph even" - No I don't mean that. What makes you think I mean things like those? "By the way, how far have you tried in constructing a wanted algorithm?" - Fairly speaking, I'm more interested in the established practices of solving cases like that (i.e. scientific papers/books discussing various aspects of such and related tasks), rather than "original research" in Wikipedia terms. After an hour in google, I wasn't able to find any materials on that (well, average curriculum is rare to even mention that DFS is not unique), hence I posted a question here.

Comment: OK, I love the way you keep me (and all other readers I assume) guessing. So what do you mean by "graph"? Not a directed acyclic graph. Not an undirected graph. So it must mean a directed graph. Right?

Comment: I appreciate your attention to making my question to be suitable as an input to automatic theorem prover ;-). I updated the question to mention directed graphs explicitly. But I hope that even automated theorem provers would agree that "a graph" means arbitrary graph, and there's no need to write "not just a DAG, not just a tree, not just a chordal graph, ..." ad infinitum ;-).

Comment: I am not investigating this question any more. Others please pick up.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. Why is b preferable to c? And why does it even matter? DFS will give you b, not c. What is the problem?

Comment: It's all in the description. We define "preferable" as "DFS spanning tree containing maximum number of forward edges (in preference of cross edges)". Algorithm adhering to this (formal) criteria is sought. Now, if you, separately to the answer to the previous question, want to criticize the criteria, please certainly do. Preferably, with links to scientific papers and/or books.